# Notify server to client via Web service

Tags: web-services, soap, webservice-client

I made a WebService chat. At the client side I am running a thread to check periodically if there any new messages available.

I want to know is there are any way to notify clients via Web Service.

I found something call 'Solicit Response' related to web service. But I am not aware how it works.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solicit/Response as well as Notification are Message exchange patterns that are defined by the WSDL specification but are not supported by web services though. They are patterns for the communication of the web service to the web client but due to the ambiguity of the specs they are not addressed by web services. To achieve what you want, your client must expose a web method, which your server will call (acting as a client at this point) to send the result. Essentially you will have 2 peers and your client will be also a web service.